# PostgreSQL: медленно работает with recursive

Tags: postgresql

Всем привет.
Таблица имеет такой вид

| Подписка | Начало подписки | Конец подписки |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Один | 01-01-2021 | 15-03-2021 |
| Два | 07-02-2021 | 07-05-2021 |
| Три | 30-03-2021 | 15-09-2021 |

мне нужен запрос, который выводит количество подписок, которые "зацепляют" месяц хоть на один день. Условно:

| Месяц | Количество подписок |
| --- | --- |
| Январь 2021 | 1 |
| Февраль 2021 | 2 |
| Март 2021 | 3 |
| Апрель 2021 | 2 |
| Май 2021 | 2 |
| Июнь 2021 | 1 |
| Ибль 2021 | 1 |
| Август 2021 | 1 |
| Сентябрь 2021 | 1 |

я этого добился с помощью WITH RECURSIVE, по сути каждую итерацию брал границы нового месяца и выбирал подписки WHERE 'Начало подписки' < 'Конца месяца' AND 'Конец подписки' > 'Начало месяца'. Все это как я сказал работает, но работает медленно, вплоть до того, что мне этот запрос на 20к подписок и периода на 4 года (брал по месяцу) пришлось разделить на 3 части по полтора года а потом склеить результаты UNION'ом. Может кто знает другой подход, пошустрее?

Comment: А нафига рекурсия, когда есть вменяемый generate_series? добавляешь в источник данных и связываешь по пересечению.

Comment: Попробовал на другой таблице, которая рекурсивным with заполнялась за 40 секунд. с generate_series заполнилась за 0,5 секунд.
Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Рекурсия, как сказал выше @Akina, в Вашей задаче не очень нужна. Но можно рассмотреть пример с рекурсией. Думаю, он будет побыстрее Вашего текущего варианта.

```
with recursive r1 as(
  select 1 l
     ,date_trunc('month',"Начало подписки") mm
     ,"Подписка","Начало подписки","Конец подписки"
  from test
  union all
  select l+1 l
     ,date_trunc('month',mm+ interval '1 month') mm
     ,"Подписка","Начало подписки","Конец подписки"
  from r1
  where date_trunc('month',mm+ interval '1 month')<="Конец подписки"
  and l<10
)
select * from r1
```

Результат рекурсивного запроса далее можно группировать и получить нужный результат. Надо ли дополнительно сделать JOIN с generate_series для полного периода - смотрите сами.

| l | mm | Подписка | Начало подписки | Конец подписки |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00+00 | Один | 2021-01-01 | 2021-03-15 |
| 2 | 2021-02-01 00:00:00+00 | Один | 2021-01-01 | 2021-03-15 |
| 3 | 2021-03-01 00:00:00+00 | Один | 2021-01-01 | 2021-03-15 |
| 1 | 2021-02-01 00:00:00+00 | Два | 2021-02-07 | 2021-05-07 |
| 2 | 2021-03-01 00:00:00+00 | Два | 2021-02-07 | 2021-05-07 |
| 3 | 2021-04-01 00:00:00+01 | Два | 2021-02-07 | 2021-05-07 |
| 4 | 2021-05-01 00:00:00+01 | Два | 2021-02-07 | 2021-05-07 |
| 1 | 2021-03-01 00:00:00+00 | Три | 2021-03-30 | 2021-09-15 |
| 2 | 2021-04-01 00:00:00+01 | Три | 2021-03-30 | 2021-09-15 |
| 3 | 2021-05-01 00:00:00+01 | Три | 2021-03-30 | 2021-09-15 |
| 4 | 2021-06-01 00:00:00+01 | Три | 2021-03-30 | 2021-09-15 |
| 5 | 2021-07-01 00:00:00+01 | Три | 2021-03-30 | 2021-09-15 |
| 6 | 2021-08-01 00:00:00+01 | Три | 2021-03-30 | 2021-09-15 |
| 7 | 2021-09-01 00:00:00+01 | Три | 2021-03-30 | 2021-09-15 |

Группировку нужно делать по расчетному полю mm

```
select mm,count(*) cnt
from r1
group by mm
order by mm;
```

Результат

| mm | cnt |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 00:00:00+00 | 1 |
| 2021-02-01 00:00:00+00 | 2 |
| 2021-03-01 00:00:00+00 | 3 |
| 2021-04-01 00:00:00+01 | 2 |
| 2021-05-01 00:00:00+01 | 2 |
| 2021-06-01 00:00:00+01 | 1 |
| 2021-07-01 00:00:00+01 | 1 |
| 2021-08-01 00:00:00+01 | 1 |
| 2021-09-01 00:00:00+01 | 1 |

Upd1. Условие `and l<10` в запросе - только для отладки, ограничить рекурсию при ошибке в запросе.

Comment: Да, так и сделал.  
Про Generate_series не знал, буду пробовать